# Deploying a project on RAD

Tags: rad

When we deploy a web/ejb project on WAS from inside RAD, does it compile the project and then deploy? I ask this because sometimes, the project has no build errors, but when i try to deploy it says Publish failed and the project is marked red with build errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check if under `Project` in the menu `Build automatically` is checked and in your server properties the option `Run server with resources within the workspace` should be selected.

If this doesn't help, you'll need to post more information !